# Workflow for Item rename.

Tags: workflow

I am wondering if you can implement Workflow for item renames in Sitecore. 
It so happens that our marketing team occasionally change the name of the item thereby changing its URL.  But sometimes, they don't want the item to change its name until launch.

I am wondering if there is a way renames can be brought into the workflow.
The other option I can think of is - not use the old item but create a duplicate of it.
Just wanted to see what others are thinking

Answer (score 2):

This functionality does not come out of the box. The item name is not versioned at all, so any change to the item name that is published will automatically change the URL. Even if you use the `Display Name` to generate the Urls, the display name is `unversioned`, so while it can have multiple language versions, changing it will still affect all versions of the item.

#### Make Copies - Use Publish Restrictions

You could work around it, but creating a copy of the item, then renaming the new one and setting publish restrictions on both the original and the copy. Disabling the original at the same time as enabling the new. You would also want to make sure your content editors handled 301 redirects for these too.

#### Custom Url Generation

If you really wanted, you *could* add a new field to your templates which was `Versioned` and then create a custom `LinkProvider` and `ItemResolver` that uses that field as the Url segment name. I would probably advise against this as it has a number of potential issues with performance etc.. But it would not be too hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

One way you might be able to do this is to use the Display Name field for URLs instead of the item name. This also enables you to support multilingual URLs as well, in case that is a need.

By default, this field is Unversioned, which means you would have to change this on the Sitecore field definition in order to support versioning for Workflow.

I have not done that personally, so I'm not sure what sort of impact it would have to the Content Editor (since it uses the Display Name).

You'd also need to make sure you source-control that change in some way to preserve the customization between upgrades, otherwise it would likely revert during an upgrade. Something to watch for, at least, if you go that route.